# How to Monitoring Docker Compose Containers Logs in Docker Desktop

Tags: docker, visual-studio, docker-compose, devops, docker-desktop

When I run the compose using the Visual Studio play button, it displays the information as I expected [image]

When I execute the compose using an automation script, the logs don't appear [image]

How can I enable this? I've tried adding tty: true for each container in the compose file, and running the docker-compose logs command, but none of them seem to work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your automation script? Are you doing a full build of your images?

Comment: full build from a git clone, then `cd` to the clone like `docker-compose -p smart-v5-compose down` and `docker-compose -p smart-v5-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml build --no-cache` and `docker-compose -p smart-v5-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml up -d`

Comment: VS does magic to override the entrypoint when running in VS (needed for starting under the debugger). By any chance is the entrypoint for your images / services not configured correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended solution for this issue is to run the command `docker-compose logs --follow`. In most cases, this command will enable the live streaming of logs within the Docker Compose view in the Docker App for Windows. I have personally tested this approach and found it effective in resolving the problem.